# CSS3 Skew trick

Tags: css, transform

I would like to know how to achieve that in CSS3[image]

I would like to know how to make the div bigger on one side and smaller on the other side
But at the same time the content is NOT skewed of affected

i tried prespective:300;
it gives the effect needed partially but the content is still affected and a negative value doesn't fix it.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm I think you can use a `inner div`.
 First, skew the parent div. 
Second, `unskew` the inner div.
 If you `skew` the parent with `50deg`, then unskew the child with `-50deg`. 
I hope this helps. Good luck!!!